# ActiveRecord single table inheritance - how to get root model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, single-table-inheritance

I have a model using single table inheritance and a concern that should work on any model.

Consider this example:

```
class Car
  acts_as_categorizable
end

class Suv < Car; end

module Categorizable
  def after_safe
    siblings = this.class.where(category: self.category)
    #... do something with the siblings
  end
end
```

Now if I have an `Suv` and manipulate its category, the siblings line will only find the other `Suv` cars in that category, but I need to find all cars in that category.

I don't want to hardcode this, so given a `Suv` class, I need to find its root model (`Car`).

Comment: For that you have to establish has_many and belongs_to  relation b/w car & suvs

Comment: Your module has to work on non-car models as well? If not, one option would be to query the Car model `Car.where(category: self.category)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's actually already a method for this; [`base_class`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/base_class/class). So `Suv.base_class` should return `Car`, and any subclass of `Suv` will also return `Car` with this method.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
module Categorizable
  def after_save
    # Get the base class. Please note, this will work on 1 level deep STI
    klass = self.type.blank? ? self.class : self.class.superclass

    siblings = klass.where(category: self.category)

    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: What if there are multiple subclasses?

Comment: There can be multiple subclasses (`B<A, C<A`), but the code does not check for multiple levels of subclassing (`B<A, C<B`). In that case, you have a snippet. Just update it to your needs.

Comment: Thanks, I already have a solution that works for that case too. I will post it if no one comes up with a better one tomorrow.